# Does collection view controller have method will display like table view controller?

Tags: ios, swift3

Today I have some problem with collection view that I can't find method will display like table view controller, so anyone can help me?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Do you want the layout to display like a tableview??

Answer (score 0):

[image]I don't think there is a method that automatically display a collection as a `UITableView`. However you can force the collection view layout to look like a `UITableView` using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout()`

The following will look like this

```
func setCollectionViewLayout() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cView.frame.width, height: 100)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)

    // cView is yout collection view
    cView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Comment: Thank your bro  for your answer :)

Comment: does it work for you??... if it did please mark it as correct for other people reference... Happy coding